# How do i hide items already selected in the checkboxes in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So, i have this model on my app:

```
class Loan(models.Model):

loan_device = models.OneToOneField(Device, max_length=50, verbose_name='Dispositivo de Empréstimo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Important: **loan_device** it's a **One To One** relationship with **Device** model

On Django Admin, when someone choose any Device registered, it keeps showing in the checkboxes, even though it was previously selected. My question is: How do i hide items already selected in the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Loan(models.Model):
    loan_device = models.OneToOneField(
        Device,
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Dispositivo de Empréstimo',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
        limit_choices_to=Q(loan=None)
    )
```